# How to findout where spam is coming from with EXIM?

Tags: php, spam, exim

I've tracked down the user which was sending out spam but I am wondering how can I determine where the script is that is doing it?

I ran a scan looking for the mail() function but found nothing. maldet also found nothing.

Can I add something to PHP and/or EXIM to better track down where the script location is?

I am running suphp and php 5.x with apache

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `mail.add_x_header` directive in PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.add-x-header

It will add an additional mail header with the name of the originating script.